# What is the set $\text{Span}(\sin(x),\cos(x))\cap \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $\text{Span}(\sin(x),\cos(x))\cap \mathbb{R}.$

I know that $\text{Span}(\sin x,\cos x)=\{a\sin x+b\cos x:a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}.$ Now $a\sin x+b\cos x$ is a real number and so $\text{Span}(\sin x,\cos x)\subset \mathbb{R}.$ Thus we have that $\text{Span}(\sin(x),\cos(x))\cap \mathbb{R}=\text{Span}(\sin x,\cos x).$ But the book says that the $$\text{Span}(\sin(x),\cos(x))\cap \mathbb{R}=\{0\}.$$ Why?

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: The question means: Among the functions $a\sin x + b\cos x$, what are the constant functions?

Comment: Linear Algebra Challenging Problems by Fuzhen Zhang.

Comment: @SuperMario Start looking for a better book.

Comment: @GEdgar So we want for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$ $a\sin x+b\cos x=r.$ Do I have to solve for $x$?

Comment: Both sides are functions of $x$.  They should be equal functions. Find $a,b,r$ so that the equation holds for all $x$.  I think solving for $x$ will not help.

Comment: @GEdgar Is it possible to intersect a set of functions with real numbers?

Comment: I assume each real number is identified with a constant function.  Presumably that is explained in the book before this point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a\sin x+b\cos x$ is a constant $c$. Plugging in $x=0,\pi$ we get respectively $a\cdot 0+b\cdot 1=c$ and $a\cdot 0+b\cdot(-1)=c$, i.e. $b=c=-b$. From there it follows that $c=0$, so $0$ is the only constant in $\mathrm{Span}(\sin x,\cos x)$.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how the downvoter would like to see this answer improved.

Answer (score 1):

Because if not then  $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=c\ne0$ for all $x$ which is absurde. On the other hand if $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=\cos(x)$ then $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent functions so $af+bg=0$ implkies $a=b=0$.Therefore the conclusion of your book.

Comment: Why is this "absurde"?

Comment: For example, for $x=0$ you have $b=c$ y por $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ $a=c$ and for $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ you have (after simplification of the common value $a=b=c$ with $c\ne 0$  you have $\sqrt 2=1$. In general you have many distinct values for cosinus and sinus while  the constants  $a,b,c$ are fixes.

Comment: This should've been included in the answer.

Comment: Next time when I say 2 + 2 is even I will be careful not to get a downvote because I did not put equal to 4.